# How to find XDG user directories if specified system-wide

Tags: linux, xdg

TLDR: How do I find the current settings for my XDG user directories **other than** invoking `xdg-user-dir`?

I'm on a system that specifies non-standard XDG user directories in `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`. I'm having a problem with some program (not sure which one yet) constantly creating the default (wrong) directories, and at the moment, I'm trying to figure out what programs "should" see as the paths to them. The way to query the values of these directories seems to be to invoke `xdg-user-dir <WHICH_DIRECTORY>`. For example, in the default scheme,

```
user@host$ xdg-user-dir PICTURES
/home/user/Pictures
```

However, this only gives me

```
user@host$ xdg-user-dir DESKTOP
/home/user/Desktop
user@host$ xdg-user-dir ANYTHING_ELSE_AT_ALL
/home/user
```

which is not correct.

I've been through [the source code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-user-dirs/) for `xdg-user-dir`, and it turns out that this program checks only the user-specific file defaulting to `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` (which does not exist on this system), and if it does not find the information there, blindly outputs the hard-coded (wrong) values that I'm getting. It completely ignores the system-wide configuration file.

`printenv` confirms that `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` is set to `/etc/xdg`, as it should be, but `xdg-user-dir` ignores this environment variable

So, in this case, how do I determine what values programs are seeing for the paths of these directories? What do programs typically do to find them? Is there a standard way specified by XDG, or is it program- or library-specific?